# RShiny: How to access ui input in the server and use it to print specific list indexes?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have created a shiny app web page with dynamic elements to print lists. I am working with very large lists and I am accessing certain parts of these lists to do things such as plot. The user selects from a drop down menu and then the page automatically updates. Everything is working fine, but with the way I have it, my code is over 3000 lines long. I am confident there must be a more efficient way to do what I am doing without these if/else statements. The code I provided is a very stripped down version of what I am working with. I used the mtcars data set only so that my program could be reproduced.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)
library(formattable)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

list1 = list("year" = 1, "plot" = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point())
list2 = list("year" = 2, "plot" = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=disp)) + geom_point())
list3 = list("year" = 3, "plot" = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=hp)) + geom_point())
list4 = list("year" = 4, "plot" = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=drat)) + geom_point())
list5 = list("year" = 5, "plot" = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=qsec)) + geom_point())
list6 = list("year" = 6, "plot" = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp)) + geom_point())
list7 = list("year" = 7, "plot" = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp)) + geom_point())
list8 = list("year" = 8, "plot" = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=drat)) + geom_point())
list9 = list("year" = 9, "plot" = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=qsec)) + geom_point())

myFirstList = list(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8, list9)
mySecondList = list(list9, list8, list7, list6, list5, list4, list3, list2, list1)

u.n <-  1:9
names(u.n) <- u.n

ui <- shinyUI(
    navbarPage("",
               tabPanel("Home",
                        fluidPage(
                            fluidRow(column(12,
                                            selectInput("type", "",
                                                        c("1" = "1",
                                                          "2" = "2"), width = "33%")
                            )
                            )
                        )
               ),
               navbarMenu("Tab 1",
                          tabPanel("Home",

                              sidebarLayout(
                                  sidebarPanel(
                                      fluidRow(selectInput('year','Select Year', choices = u.n, width = "100%"))

                                  ),
                                  mainPanel(
                                      fluidRow(
                                          plotOutput('distPlot'),
                                          style = "padding-bottom:50px"
                                      )
                              )
                          )
                          )

               ))
)
```

server

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        if (input$year == "1"){
            if (input$type == "1"){
                myFirstList[[1]]$plot
            }
            else if (input$type == "2"){
                mySecondList[[1]]$plot
            }
        }

        else if (input$year == "2"){
            if (input$type == "1"){
                myFirstList[[2]]$plot
            }
            else if (input$type == "2"){
                mySecondList[[2]]$plot
            }
        }

        else if (input$year == "3"){
            if (input$type == "1"){
                myFirstList[[3]]$plot
            }
            else if (input$type == "2"){
                mySecondList[[3]]$plot
            }
        }

        else if (input$year == "4"){
            if (input$type == "1"){
                myFirstList[[4]]$plot
            }
            else if (input$type == "2"){
                mySecondList[[4]]$plot
            }
        }

        else if (input$year == "5"){
            if (input$type == "1"){
                myFirstList[[5]]$plot
            }
            else if (input$type == "2"){
                mySecondList[[5]]$plot
            }
        }

        else if (input$year == "6"){
            if (input$type == "1"){
                myFirstList[[6]]$plot
            }
            else if (input$type == "2"){
                mySecondList[[6]]$plot
            }
        }

        else if (input$year == "7"){
            if (input$type == "1"){
                myFirstList[[7]]$plot
            }
            else if (input$type == "2"){
                mySecondList[[7]]$plot
            }
        }

        else if (input$year == "8"){
            if (input$type == "1"){
                myFirstList[[8]]$plot
            }
            else if (input$type == "2"){
                mySecondList[[8]]$plot
            }
        }

        else if (input$year == "9"){
            if (input$type == "1"){
                myFirstList[[9]]$plot
            }
            else if (input$type == "2"){
                mySecondList[[9]]$plot
            }
        }
    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

I want something like this as the server instead but this does not work

```
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        if (input$type == "1"){
            myFirstList[[input$year]]$plot
        }

        if (input$type == "2"){
            mySecondList[[input$year]]$plot
        }
    })
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work... what does that mean? Are you getting an error? Warning? Output you don't expect?

Comment: Why not generate the plots dynamically in the server, based on what's selected? Is there a reason you have to create them all first and store them in lists?

Comment: When I say it does not work, there are no visible errors or warnings being outputted, but the plots do not show up on the app.

Comment: I cannot generate the plots in the server because the program used to generate my actual plots, and other list elements I need, takes approximately 5 minutes to run. So I have them all stored in an RDS file which I have embedded in the shiny app.

Comment: If you have to create them outside of the Shiny app, then you need to make the list indices do the job of your if() statements. Something like myCombiList = list(myFirstList, mySecondList) and then in the Shiny Server output$distPlot <- renderPlot(myCombiList[[input$type]][[input$year]]$plot.)

Comment: I just tried to run `output$distPlot <- renderPlot({myCombiList[[input$type]][[input$year]]$plot})` and that provided the same results as before: no errors but plots are not being displayed. If I type `myCombiList[[1]][[1]]$plot` in the console the first plot displays in the plot window.